# Send Messages from Amazon SQS to AWS S3 through AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am trying to store messages from AWS SQS to Amazon S3. The Lambda code is as follow, but I'm getting the following error as well. Is there anyone to help? I want to know why am I getting key error and nothing store in the S3?

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    sqs_msg = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body'])

    print("SQS Message : ", sqs_msg)

    

    bucket_name = "sqstest"

    try:
        
        s3Client = boto3.client("s3", region_name= "us-east-1")

        Response = s3Client.put_object(Bucket= bucket_name, Key= "Message.json", Body= json.dumps(sqs_msg))

        print("S3 upload success !")

        return {

            "status" : 200,

            "body" : "S3 upload success"

        }

    except Exception as e:

        print("Client connection to S3 failed because ", e)

        return{

            "status" : 500,

            "body" : "S3 upload failed"

        }
```

The error is as follow:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "'Records'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 6, in lambda_handler\n    sqs_msg = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body'])\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 4762158b-7642-42c0-a010-945086376b05 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] KeyError: 'Records'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 6, in lambda_handler
    sqs_msg = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body'])END RequestId: 4762158b-7642-42c0-a010-945086376b05
REPORT RequestId: 4762158b-7642-42c0-a010-945086376b05  Duration: 4.99 ms   Billed Duration: 5 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 51 MB  Init Duration: 249.26 ms

Request ID
4762158b-7642-42c0-a010-945086376b05
```

Comment: The error is saying your `event` object doesn't have a `Records` key. The first line of your Lambda function should print/log the `event` object so you can look at it in the logs and see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: See [Python KeyError Exceptions and How to Handle Them](https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/).

Comment: Add `print('Event:', event)` to the start of the function to see what it contains. The output will be available in CloudWatch Logs (go via the Monitor tab).

Answer (score 0):

First check if there is an event after all, if so then if event has record in it. If that's ok then get the message, I suppose you want to save the message as a txt file (or any type).

- Save it in the tmp using lambda
- Then just move to s3 -
  `s3_client.upload_fileobj(temp_file, bucket, path)`

See the [doc by aws](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html)